# grouping similar images in array using their rgb values

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

I have extracted frames from a video per second and done the shot boundary detection.
Now I am facing problem in clustering the similar images, I want to go with this Shot Clustering algorithm, I want to implement it in java but facing problem in dealing with multidimensional arrays.

1) Make N clusters, one for each shot.

2) Stop when the difference between 2 clusters is greater than a predefined threshold.

3) Find the most similar pair of clusters, R and S within a specified time constraint(50 SECONDS). 
4) Merge R and S (More specifically merge S into R).

5) Go to step 2.

But I don't know how to get similar images in one array within a specified time.
anyone can help?
Here is the my code that I have tried to implement.

```
  for(int i=1;i<files.length;i++){
           File fileIn=new 
File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\hamid\\"+i+".png");
         newimage.open_image(fileIn.toString());
        newimage.colour_histogram();
        float colorAv[]=newimage.get_colour_average();
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<colorAv.length;j++){
            sum+=colorAv[j];    //rgb value of each image
        }
        arr[i]=sum;
    }
    int[] res= new int[files.length];
    int count=0;
    res[count]=count+1;
    count++;
    for (int j=1;j<files.length;j++)
    {
        if(j>1){
        int dif = Math.abs(arr[j]-arr[j-1]); 
        if(dif>18){
        res[count]=j;
        count++;
        }
        }
    }
   System.out.println("Toral shots are"+count);
    for(int k=0; k<count;k++){
    }
    int shotdiff[]=new int[count];
   int i=0; 
            int j=0;
    int shots[][]= new int[count][count];
     int resp=0;
     int arr_count=0;
            shots[i][j]=res[resp];
            arr_count++;
            resp++;
       for(int array=0;array<count;array++){
           shotdiff[i]=Math.abs(arr[shots[i][0]]-arr[res[resp]]);
            if(shotdiff[i]<=18){
                j++;
                shots[i][j]= res[resp];
            resp++;
             }
            else {
            if(j==0){
                shots[i+1][j]= res[resp];
                resp++;
            arr_count++;
              }

     }          
        }
```

The code is working well for storing first three values but the fourth value has to be stored in a new array because it is not similar to previous images' rgb color histogram values. Now I am facing problem at this step what to do to add new array  when there is a different value from previous values

Comment: You may want to learn about java collections...

Comment: Yes I have done some research and solved the issue in getting similar images in one array.